# Wp datetime format

Tags: windows-phone

I have an app that deals with time and it shows prayer times in 12hr format only ,it is very functioning without errors.

one of my users sent me a message :

" app does not work in 24hr format,
when I changed my time setting from 24 hours to 12 hours it start work, actually here in shengun countries Nokia Lumia does not show 12 hours by default, to change the setting we would have to change region setting."

I tried to reproduce the same error but I could not ,ofcourse I am not living in Europe.

my question is what is different in Nokia Lumia in Europe from international version like in middle east from a programmer point of view ?

So I can take in account in my app next update

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is what is different in Nokia Lumia in Europe from international version like in middle east from a programmer point of view

Only one thing: the regional settings. You can change them manually on your device or the emulator by going in the settings menu (in the region+language submenu).

Unfortunately, "does not work" isn't precise enough to understand what's going on with your application. A few leads though:

- Having a time on 24 hours rather than 12 hours may change your computations
- Parsing a decimal number or a date without explicitly setting a culture in the `.Parse` method can crash when executed in a foreign culture (by far the most common crash occurrence I've seen on Windows Phone)
- The same way, converting a decimal or a date to a string without specifying a culture can yield different results depending on the country

Comment: Not specifying the culture means use default culture so I think it is safe ,And regional settings changes does not do help as you mentioned ,I can not change the code until I know where exactly it crashes,I was thinking this is a common problem and many have found solution to it.

Comment: `Not specifying the culture means use default culture` Wrong. Not specifying culture means using phone's culture, and therefore having different results depending on the settings of the user executing the app. If you know the issue is a crash, I suggest inspecting all calls to `.Parse` methods. Also, consider implementing some bug reporting mechanism in your app, by using the `Application.UnhandledException` event. This way, when a user reports an issue, you'll be able to get the full callstack and quickly pinpoint the cause.

Comment: Please tell me the name of your app, I'll test it on my side.

Comment: (Shia Prayer Times) ,That's would be a generous move

Comment: Not sure that's your issue, but: if I enter manually a city, the longitude and latitude are displayed using `.` as decimal separator. Then, the "Save" button does nothing. If I use the GPS feature, longitude and latitude will be displayed using `,` (my phone is French), and saving will work.

Comment: Also, the app crashes if I try to use the GPS feature with location services disabled on the phone. It's a minor problem, but you should handle it gracefully with an error message.

Comment: This is so weird in mine it is (.) always and I never used , in the program I reckon your phone is 24hr format and you got no errors.Thanks for the GPS although I will fix this.I think that WP is still premature unreliable and so restricted

Comment: You never used `,`, but that's the culture problem I spoke of. The GPS is returning coordinates to you (in double or decimal format, I don't remember), then you're converting them to string without specifying the culture. Therefore, the phone's culture is used, and `,` is the decimal separator used in France. That's why specifying the culture is **critical**, both when converting to and from string. It's a non-intuitive behavior that has been plaguing the .NET framework, unfortunately we're stuck with it as changing it would break many applications.

Comment: Yes. When you don't need a specific culture, always use InvariantCulture